# Does Australia impose estate tax on foreigners investing in the Australian stock market?

Tags: taxes, stocks, australia, estate-planning

Suppose a non-Australian, say a Singaporean, owns AUD $100k worth of Australian stocks and dies suddenly. Will estate tax be imposed on him? If yes, roughly how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Australia does not have estate taxes or death duties.